# Paypal auto return is not working for subscribe button

Tags: jquery, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am using `paypal` form with `paypal subscribe` button. My form is looking like this

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="payPalForm">
    <input name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" type="hidden">
    <input name="hosted_button_id" value="xyz" type="hidden">
    <input name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost.fbleads.com/user/login" type="hidden">
    <input name="return" value="http://localhost.fbleads.com/user/login" type="hidden">
    <input name="custom" value="MTA=" type="hidden">
    <input name="invoice" value="MTIzNTU=" type="hidden">
    <input name="rm" value="2" type="hidden">
    <input name="page_style" value="paypal" type="hidden">
    <input name="charset" value="utf-8" type="hidden">
</form>
```

I also `enabled` the `auto return` of my `sandbox` account. But it is not auto returning to the return url. I also offered a `trial membership` of one day for free at the time of button creation. At the time of payment it asks to login with paypal account. After login it goes to paypal account summary page but not auto returning. Anyone know, why this is happening?